# Replicar base de datos tomando en cuenta posibles cambios en la BD origen

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, mariadb

Buen día, 
Requiero "replicar" algunos campos de algunas una base de datos, el problema es que debo contemplar el hecho de que algunos datos en la BD origen se modifiquen para actualizar esos mismos en la nueva BD y no generar un nuevo registro.
En mi primer carga de datos, hice uso de un archivo PHP el cual hace la query de los campos requeridos y los inserta en la nueva BD con un INSERT IGNORE(Esto funciona bien para hacer la primer carga de datos), después me tope con el problema de que algunos valores cambian en el origen y el nuevo sistema no tiene los datos correctos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL dispone de un sistema bastante avanzado y práctico de replicación pero parece que quieres hacerlo por software. Esto NO lo recomiendo; la replicación de datos es algo complejo que un montón de gente lleva muchos años mejorando en MySQL de modo que te sugiero usarlo.

La replicación en MySQL puede ser Maestro-Esclavo, como es lo habitual, pero también admite configuraciones de doble maestro si es lo que necesitas (es como un clúster para pobres).

Échale un vistazo al manual de MySQL sobre replicación [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html).

Si es lo que quieres puedes sólo replicar algunas tablas. En realidad replicarías una base de datos pero en el esclavo le puedes decir qué datos quieres que se repliquen, así puedes replicar unos datos en un esclavo y otros en otro. Puedes ver algunas de esas opciones [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table).

Comment: Si lo vi, pero según entiendo hace la replican de la base completa, y lo que requiero es solo algunos valores, por eso lo había descartado y decidí hacerlo por fuera. Es que la BD esta muy vieja también, lleva 15 años trabajando la empresa con esta BD y no se si soporte al cien las cosas nuevas.

Comment: Se pueden replicar sólo algunas bases de datos e incluso sólo algunas tablas (cuidado si haces eso ya que si tiene claves ajenas fallará). Configurar tu servidor antiguo como maestro de replicación debería ser fácil ya que sólo necesitas establecer el id de servidor, decir qué tablas quieres replicar, crear un usuario con permisos de REPL para el esclavo y activar el log de replicación. Todo ello es sólo cambiar un archivo de texto, de modo que puedes mantener el original a mano por si algo va mal.

Comment: Excelente, así como lo dices suena fácil, esperemos que funcione, ahorita me pongo a indagar como hacerlo paso a paso igual ya tengo un respaldo de la BD del viernes pasado. Que pesa mucho la BD como para andar a cada rato respaldando. Muchísimas gracias!!.

Comment: Otra ventaja de la replicación de BD es que puedes meter en el esclavo un dump completo del maestro y luego, diciéndole por dónde ibas, él solo se pone al día. Después los backups los puedes hacer ya SIEMPRE en el esclavo, de modo que el maestro queda liberado de todas estas tareas tan costosas ¡Y sin "down-time"!